# Find the values without a calculator (Trigonometry)

Tags: trigonometry

a) $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$ given $\tan(\theta) =\frac{ 5}{12}$ and $\theta$ is acute

b) $\sin(\theta)$ and $\tan(\theta)$ given $\cos(\theta) = -\frac{3}{5}$ and $\theta$ is obtuse

c) $\cos(\theta)$ and $\tan(\theta)$ given $\sin(\theta)= -\frac{7}{25}$ and $270^{\circ}<\theta<360^{\circ}$

Comment: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing Tex. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

These ratios should look like Pythagorean triangles you know and maybe love.  For a, the definition of tangent is $\frac {\text {opposite}}{\text {adjacent}}$ so draw a right triangle with that tangent.  What is the hypotenuse?  What are the $\sin$ and $\cos?$

For the others, you can follow the same process.  You need to use the minus signs to pick the quadrant.

Answer (score 0):

From the Pythagorean identity
$$
\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1
$$
you can deduce, by division
$$
\tan^2\theta+1=\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}
$$
and
$$
1+\frac{1}{\tan^2\theta}=\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}
$$
So, when you know one of the three functions, you can deduce the absolute value of the other two. The information about the size of $\theta$ will determine the sign.